# How to solve square of Quadratic Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics, quartics

The formula looks like this:
$$
\bigl( a x^2 + b x + c \bigr)^2 = \; d
$$

What I try to solve is the following system:
\begin{align}
d_1 &= (a_1 x^2 + b_1 x + c_1)^2 \tag{1} \\
d_2 &= (a_2 x^2 + b_2 x + c_2)^2 \tag{2} \\
1 &= d_1 + d_2 \tag{3}
\end{align}
with unknowns $x$, $d_1$, and $d_2$.
I need $x$.

I know I can solve this through a $4$th degree equation but I believe this might have a much easier solution.

This comes from a real problem. I need to find the collision time (t) of 2 balls with the same R, 2R = 1
the 2nd degree formula is : $$ d = t * (v - t * a / 2)$$

where:
d - distance. $d^2=∆x^2+∆y^2$,
v - speed at t0 = 0,
a - acceleration (friction)

I know the initial speed, friction and the direction of each object.
There should be only one solution for t, or none

Comment: I think having a 4th order polynomial to solve is a lot better than having one $n \geq 5$

Comment: Take the square root first.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid solving a quartic equation for generic coefficients and square-sum $d$. Mess around with coefficients [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/exckn81dwl) to get a feel for the problem.

Comment: @SammyBlack I disagree.  Without loss of generality, $d > 0$ [else there are no solutions, or the problem reduces to a quadratic].  Then $$r^2 = d > 0 \implies \{r = \sqrt{d} \vee r = -\sqrt{d}\}.$$  So, the problem immediately reduces to two distinct quadratic equations.

Comment: I'm addressing the question of finding solutions to the system of three numbered equations, which doesn't reduce to the simpler first equation that OP writes unless the coefficient vectors are scalar multiples of one another.

Comment: The system does not reduce to the first equation, that first equation is a substitute for d1 or d2 when d=d1^2+d2^2

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a particularly complicated quartic to solve.  Really unclear why you are introducing more variables to create a system of equations

First, let $d_-=-\sqrt d, d_+=\sqrt d$.  Then, we have two solutions that are solutions to the quadratic $ax^2+bx+c=d_-$ and two that are solutions to $ax^2+bx+c=d_+$.

That in mind, we can apply the quadratic formula to the equations $ax^2+bx+c=\pm\sqrt{d}$ and get roots $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac\pm4a\sqrt{d}}}{2a}$

Comment: None of these 2 d's (d_ and d+) are known so in the end I have no solution, the only thing I know about one of them is that $d^2=d1^2+d2^2$, where $d1^2=[d_,d+]$

Comment: If you know $d$, then you can solve the equation.  If you don't, then it's really unclear from your post what you do know

Comment: @AntalAlin Your post is unclear. Usually, in an expression like $(ax^2+bx+c)^2=d$, it is understood that $x$ is the unknown variable and the other letters are constants. That's why we use symbols from different sections of the alphabet. Your post looks like you are trying to solve the first equation by generating the second set of equations.

Comment: the knowns and unknowns are in the system,
 I can easily sum up both 2nd degree equations and end up with a 4th degree one but is there a much easier solution to this?